# Puppeteer is not found after Dockerization

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, puppeteer-sharp

My issue arises when running my code on a Linux system within a Docker container. The code, which downloads and launches Puppeteer, works flawlessly on my Windows machine. Here's the relevant snippet:

```
var browserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher();
var installedBrowser = await browserFetcher.DownloadAsync(BrowserTag.Latest);
var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
{
    Headless = true,
    ExecutablePath = browserFetcher.GetExecutablePath(installedBrowser.BuildId)
});
```

I specifically utilize GetExecutablePath(installedBrowser.BuildId) to avoid hardcoding directories. However, upon building and running the Docker container with an Alpine Linux image, I encounter the following error:

```
Error: An error occurred trying to start process '/app/Chrome/Linux-124.0.6335.0/chrome-linux64/chrome' with working directory '/app'. No such file or directory
```

Upon inspecting the container using /bin/sh, I find the necessary files exist:
[image]

I'm perplexed by this issue. If further information is required, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I recommend you to install the browser beforehand when you create the docker image. There are many recipes in the web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PuppeteerProject/PuppeteerProject.csproj", "PuppeteerProject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "PuppeteerProject/PuppeteerProject.csproj"

COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/PuppeteerProject"
RUN dotnet build "PuppeteerProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PuppeteerProject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
        wget \
        gnupg2 \
        apt-transport-https \
        ca-certificates \
        fonts-liberation \
        libappindicator3-1 \
        libasound2 \
        libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
        libatk1.0-0 \
        libcups2 \
        libdbus-1-3 \
        libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
        libnspr4 \
        libnss3 \
        libx11-xcb1 \
        libxcomposite1 \
        libxdamage1 \
        libxrandr2 \
        xdg-utils \
        libgbm1 \
        libxcb-dri3-0 \
        libxss1 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["dotnet", "PuppeteerProject.dll"]
```

The long list of dependencies in the third build stage is to support the browser runtime.

`Program.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using PuppeteerSharp;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        await new BrowserFetcher().DownloadAsync();
        var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions
        {
            Headless = true,
            Args = new string[] { "--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox" }
        });

        Console.WriteLine("Browser launched successfully.");

        await browser.CloseAsync();
    }
}
```

[image]

The example `Program.cs` will run and then exit. When it exits the container will terminate.

You can, however, get a more persistent container by commenting out the `CMD` line in the `Dockerfile`. Then just run it manually.

[image]

Comment: but would there be a way to use it with an Apline-Image?

Comment: Aha! Have you checked that the container is still running? Because my setup above will run the container and when it's done the container will exit. If you want to connect to the container then it needs to do some persistent job. I'll update my answer.

Comment: THANK you so much for your reply. 
to be honest, i dont know what the problem was. not everything works perfectly.
but after i tryed some things out, i endet up doing exactly the same thing i did before and now it works.
i wanted to also aks you if the long list of dependecys needs to be this big. but... yeah.. it needs to be that big...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately browsers come with a bunch of dependencies. You might consider a more lightweight browser but TBH I'd be pragmatic about this: accept the dependencies and a larger image, just focus on functionality.